# decode netCDF file when downloading data from request module python

Tags: python, python-requests, netcdf

I am trying to download netCDF file from [NASA GES DISC](https://disc.gsfc.nasa.gov/datasets/GPM_3IMERGHH_06/summary). There are 1000 netCDF file links in a text file and I want to download it using request module. The response status code is 200 but the content of the file is not in the format I want. I am unable to decode it.

```
import requests
result = requests.get(myURL)
result.content.decode()
```

This results in `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x89 in position 0: invalid start byte`.

The content of the file is returned in the following format `b'\x89HDF\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x08\x08\x00\x04\x00\x10\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff...`

How do I decode the result. Are there any alternatives to downloading from url?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question, you have a list of urls that provide links to netCDF files and you want to download them all. The code below shows you how to do it for one, saving it as a temporary file:

```
import urllib
url = "ftp://ftp.cdc.noaa.gov/Datasets/COBE/sst.mon.ltm.1981-2010.nc"
new = "/tmp/tmp.nc"
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, new)
```